# Constant space label titleformat

Tags: titlesec

I have trouble with `\titleformat`.

I have modified the title format using `titlesec` package. I am using the Roman enum by obligation and increasing the number the space increases (see figure). Does anyone know how I can leave that separation constant and independent of the size of the label?

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{20mm}{\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to use a minimal spacing, you might load `eqparbox` and use the`\eqmakebox[tag]` command: all such boxes sharing the same tag have a width corresponding to the widest contents.

Unrelated: it's not necessary to specify the `hang` style – it's the default. Also, needless to repeat the font specifications: the first mandatory argument of `\titleformat` is a global assignment (label + title).

```
\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont\bfseries}{\eqmakebox[Sec][l]{\thesection.}}{20mm}{\MakeUppercase}
```